# WordPress returns to an old version

Tags: database, cache

I'm creating a WordPress site and today it has returned to an old version of himself. I don't mean a downgrade, but it has changed the slider, menu's links, widgets, etc to as it was weeks ago.

How can I find out the cause and why it has changed? I had debug lines in wp-config.php defined as false, so I can't look any log file.

Comment: are you using any caching plugins? Has the actual data changed, or just the appearance (i.e. when you log into the dashboard and visit Appearance > Widgets, Appearance > Menus, and the slider administration, do they show the new or old configuration?)

Comment: Did you accidentally restore a backup of your site? If not, maybe your hosting provider did that, if they had some trouble with your server, they might have done that. Also check if you have a caching plugin active. Providing more information on this issue will help us understand your problem better.